# Ruby on rails. Sorting my model in a table using scopes and attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, attributes

I've been at this for ages and can't get it right. I have a `gig` model and a couple of tables. In each table I need to show only gigs that meet certain requirements but there is one table that I cannot figure out.

This table must contain gigs where:

- not expired (date attribute NOT in the past)
- expired BUT with filled == true (date attribute in past but filled attribute true)

The table must NOT contain gigs where:

- Expired and NOT filled. (date attribute in the past and filled attribute == false)

my scopes:

```
scope :expiredr, -> { where('gigzonetime <= ?', Time.current.to_datetime)}
scope :notfilled, -> {where(filled: false)}
scope :filled, -> {where(filled: true)}
scope :expired_and_filled, ->() {self.expiredr.merge(self.filled)}
scope :expired_and_notfilled, ->() { self.expiredr.merge(self.notfilled) }
```

I have tried loads of variations, eg.

Controller:

```
def dashboard
    if user_signed_in? && !current_user.try(:artist?)
      @activegigs = current_user.gigs.notcompleted.where.not(:expired_and_notfilled)
      @q = @activegigs.ransack(params[:q])
      @dashgigs = @q.result(distinct: true).order(filled: :desc, reviewed: :desc, date: :asc).page(params[:page]).per(20)
  else
     redirect_to(root_url)
     flash[:danger] = "This page is for registered hosts only"
   end
 end
```

which gives an

```
RuntimeError at /gigs/dashboard

unsupported: Symbol
```

OR

```
@activegigs = current_user.gigs.notcompleted && current_user.gigs.expired_and_filled && current_user.gigs.notexpired
```

Which only shows expired_and_filled gigs.

I am not sure how to negate the expired_and_notfilled scope or if that's even necessary. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the logic seems to only need to be !expired OR filled.  There is no need for the !expired OR (expired and filled) NOT (expired and filled) logic tree.  This constructs a simple where query:

```
.where('gigzonetime > ? OR filled IS TRUE', Time.current.to_datetime)
```

Comment: This does appear to be working. I had no idea how to make the 'OR' query, thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Using ransack, we need to have an OR condition for `not_expired` and `expired_and_filled` to satisfy the table content as you have mentioned.

Add a new scope, and whitelist the two scopes to be filterable by ransack using `ransackable_scopes` [(documentation here)](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#user-content-using-scopesclass-methods)

```
# gig.rb
scope :not_expired, -> { where('gigzonetime > ?', Time.current.to_datetime) }

def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
  [:not_expired, :expired_and_filled]
end
```

Now we can combine the query using the advanced ransack using 'OR' instead of the default 'AND' [(documentation here)](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#user-content-grouping-queries-by-or-instead-of-and)

You need to make sure that

```
params[:q] == {m: 'or', not_expired: true, expired_and_filled: true }
```

You can pass `m: 'or'` through a `hidden_field` so that `params` will look like above.

The following should then work properly already.

```
@q = Gig.ransack(params[:q])
@gigs = @q.result(distinct: true).order(filled: :desc, reviewed: :desc, date: :asc).page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

`@gigs` should now include gigs not_expired and gigs expired_and_filled together

Comment: I was in the middle of trying your answer when the above answer was posted and it does seem much simpler. Thankyou for your reply though, I have looked through the docs you linked to and I will be able to use this for other things in my project.

Comment: @RobHughes No problem! :) This solution is for Ransack though. But Andy's answer above is the way to go, if you don't care about the ransack params. You might want to put that into a scope as well.